# How to get a specific value from a JSON file based on another value in the JSON object in Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, android, json, api

I'm trying to put together a Mock API for my app in Android Studio using JSON, and I am trying to work out how to get a specific value from the JSON file?

For example, I want to the get the "horoscope" string from the array "horoscopes" where the "sunsign" string equals "aries".

This could be super simple, but I'm not too sure where to start.

Here's my JSON:

```
  "horoscopes": [
    {
      "horoscopeId": 1,
      "sunsign": "aquarius",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for aquarius",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 2,
      "sunsign": "pisces",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for pisces",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 3,
      "sunsign": "aries",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for aries",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 4,
      "sunsign": "taurus",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for taurus",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 5,
      "sunsign": "gemini",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for gemini",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 6,
      "sunsign": "cancer",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for cancer",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 7,
      "sunsign": "leo",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for leo",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 8,
      "sunsign": "virgo",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for virgo",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 9,
      "sunsign": "libra",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for libra",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 10,
      "sunsign": "scorpio",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for scorpio",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 11,
      "sunsign": "sagittarius",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for sagittarius",
    },
    {
      "horoscopeId": 12,
      "sunsign": "capricorn",
      "month": "january",
      "horoscope": "I am the january horoscope for capricorn",
    }
 ]
}
```

Here's what I've got so far for connecting to the JSON:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class horoscope extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> horoscope_al = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horoscope);

        
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray horoscopeArray = obj.getJSONArray("horoscopes");
            for (int i = 0; i < horoscopeArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject horoscopeValues = horoscopeArray.getJSONObject(i);
                horoscope_al.add(horoscopeValues.getString("horoscope"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset()
    {
        String json_string = null;
        try {
            InputStream inpSt = getAssets().open("horoscope_api.json");
            int s = inpSt.available();
            byte[] buffer_byte = new byte[s];
            inpSt.read(buffer_byte);
            inpSt.close();
            json_string = new String(buffer_byte, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json_string;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class horoscope extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button back_btn;
    TextView horoscope_txt;
    String al_string = " ";

    ArrayList<String> horoscope_al = new ArrayList<>();
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horoscope);

        horoscope_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.horoscope_txt);
        back_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent back_intent = new Intent(horoscope.this, menu.class);
                startActivity(back_intent);
            }
        });


       try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray horoscopeArray = obj.getJSONArray("horoscopes");

            List<String> horoscopesOfAries = IntStream.range(0, horoscopeArray.length())
                    .mapToObj(horoscopeArray::getJSONObject)
                    .filter(horoscopeJson -> horoscopeJson.getString("sunsign").equals("aries"))
                    .map(horoscopeJson -> horoscopeJson.getString("horoscope"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            /*for (int i = 0; i < horoscopeArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject horoscopeValues = horoscopeArray.getJSONObject(i);
                horoscope_al.add(horoscopeValues.getString("horoscope"));
                al_string += horoscope_al.get(i);
            }*/
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //horoscope_txt.setText(al_string);
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset()
    {
        String json_string = null;
        try {
            InputStream inpSt = getAssets().open("horoscope_api.json");
            int s = inpSt.available();
            byte[] buffer_byte = new byte[s];
            inpSt.read(buffer_byte);
            inpSt.close();
            json_string = new String(buffer_byte, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json_string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
JSONArray horoscopeArray = obj.getJSONArray("horoscopes");

List<String> horoscopesOfAries = IntStream.range(0, horoscopeArray.length())
        .mapToObj(horoscopeArray::getJSONObject)
        .filter(horoscopeJson -> horoscopeJson.getString("sunsign").equals("aries"))
        .map(horoscopeJson -> horoscopeJson.getString("horoscope"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[I am the january horoscope for aries]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The only thing is that the "mapToObj(horoscopeArray::getJSONObject)" bit is throwing an error saying "Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException", do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @ells99 I think the JSON is missing a '{' in the beginning. After adding it, I got that output. You can make sure the JSON with this tool - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Ah yes thank you, I think that's my rubbish copying and pasting :/ I have just checked my JSON with the tool and it's all valid, but the error is still there, so I'm not too sure what else could be causing it

Comment: @ells99 does it detail the error? this line just is horoscopeArray.getJSONObject(i) for each json in the array

Comment: Ah okay, it says "Returns the value at index if it exists and is a JSONObject. Throws org.json.JSONException - if the value doesn't exist or is not a JSONObject." But it's already in a try catch?

Comment: @ells99 Since this code works for me with the provoded JSON, can you update what exactly you tried to do? Try to isolate the reason for the error.

Comment: Yeah sure, I've added my updated code to the question above

Comment: @ells99  I have just copied the updated try & catch and it works perfectly with the provided JSON. Try to replace 'loadJSONFromAsset()' with the JSON hardcoded. I think the method 'loadJSONFromAsset()' is the problem, can you look at stacktrace?.